# Is Q_INTERFACES macro needed for child classes?

Tags: c++, qt, interface, qobject

If I have class `A` that implements an interface (and uses `Q_INTERFACES` macro), then does child class `B : public A` also need to use the `Q_INTERFACES` macro?

For example:

**IMovable.h**

```
#include <QObject>

class IMovable
{
public slots:
    virtual void moveLeft(int distance) = 0;
    virtual void moveRight(int distance) = 0;
    virtual void moveUp(int distance) = 0;
    virtual void moveDown(int distance) = 0;
signals:
    virtual void moved(int x, int y) = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IMovable, "my_IMovable")
```

**A.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include "IMovable.h"

class A : public QObject, public IMovable
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(IMovable)
public:
    explicit A(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~A();

public slots:
    //implement IMovable public slots
    void moveLeft(int distance) override;
    void moveRight(int distance) override;
    void moveUp(int distance) override;
    void moveDown(int distance) override;

signals:
    //implement IMovable signals
    void moved(int x, int y) override;
};
```

**B.h**

```
#include "A.h"

class B : public A
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // Do I need Q_INTERFACES(IMovable) here?
    ...
};
```

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Plugins

Comment: @MarekR I have read that page and I don't believe it covers my question. Child classes, such as `B : public A` where `A : public QObject` also need to include the macro `Q_OBJECT`. Hence my question whether `Q_INTERFACES` also needs to be included.

Comment: `Q_OBJECT` is a building block of Qt metasystem hence it should be added virtually everywhere.

Comment: Just try both version and see what code has been generated by moc tool. See contents of `void *B::qt_metacast(const char *iname)`. Based on example in link it is needed (I do not see that supper class method is called).

Comment: @ixSci Indeed, but that still leaves my question.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question can be found by the link provided by Marek and depends only on the intended usage of the `B` class which you didn't mention in your question. Right now both answers are valid: "yes you need `Q_INTERFACES`" and "no you don't"

Comment: I've reread Marek's link. I think the relevant bit is about `Q_INTERFACES` adding code to `B::q_metacast()`. Comparing the moc with/without, I see it adds `if (!strcmp(_clname, "my_IMovable")) return static_cast< IMovable*>(this);`. But what does this do? And what is the significance? I tried a test app that invoked `moveLeft()` after `qobject_cast` `A*` to `IMovable*`, `B*` to `IMovable*` and `B*` to `A*`. The results were the same regardless of `Q_INTERFACES()` being present in `B`. I also tried removing `Q_INTERFACES()` from `A` and this crashes on `qobject_cast` `A*` to `IMovable*`.

Comment: @ixSci Your last comment is quite cryptic. Can you elaborate, and perhaps provide an answer that could help me and perhaps others who have this question in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q_INTERFACES` is needed for the [`qobject_cast`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#qobject_cast-1) function to work correctly with the interfaces a class implements. So if you want to use this function you have to place `Q_INTERFACES` into your class.

Docs aren't clear on what happens with the inheritance but the implementation of the generated `qt_metacast` function is always calling their parent `qt_metacast`. So in your example, even if you don't put the `Q_INTERFACES` macro into the `B` class it should still work with the `qobject_cast` function because it would pass it to `A` to execute.